# mapping object in linq (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to map t and q .how can i do that? (In asp.net)

I want to get t and map it to q for editing the record

```
public void EdittblUser(tblUser t)
{
    var q = db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == t.userName );
    //mapping here
    dbconnect.submitchange();
}
```

some thing like this :

```
 var user = 
    dbconnect.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == _VOUser.Username);

if (user == null)
    // throw exception

Mapper.Map(tbluser, user);
dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
return true;
```

Comment: What do you mean saying that you want map t and q; Please be more specific on what you want in order to think about it and provide you with some help.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to copy the values of all the members of `t` into the equivalent members of `q`?

Comment: Yes exactly.t and q are the same object of tbluser

Comment: Mapper.Map(tbluser, user);.....i can't find this function  in my project

Comment: Err, what is stopping you from writing a series of assignments like `q.Foo = t.Foo; q.Bar = t.Bar;`?

Comment: yes i don't want to write these :t.Foo = q.Foo; t.Bar = q.Bar

Comment: If you want this kind of functionality, take a look at AutoMapper

Comment: so how can i use automapper

Comment: Try searching for "AutoMapper" on this site or in a search engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public void EdittblUser(tblUser t)
{
    var q = db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == t.userName );
    if(q==null)
       // throw exception

    q.Property1=t.Property1;
    q.Property2=t.Property2;
    // and so on
    dbconnect.submitchange();
}
```

where `Property1`, `Property2` and so on are the properties of the user object. (For instance they would be the userId, the userName and so on).

The other way for editing your record would be using AutoMapper this way:

```
// I suppose that you have made a reference of AutoMapper assembly in your project.
// Having done this then you should include it to your source file using the using 
// statement 
using AutoMapper;

public void EdittblUser(tblUser t)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>();
    var q = db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == t.userName );
    q = Mapper.Map(Model1, Model2)(t); 
    dbconnect.submitchange();
}
```

Where Model1 and Model2 are the classes you want to create a mapping between them.

However, since both t and q are of the same type, I don't see why you should use this.
For further clarification about AutoMapper, please check this one link in codeproject:

```
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639618/CRUD-Opearations-using-AutoMapper-in-an-MVC-Applic][1]
```

Comment: I know that ,i don't want to write this code .i want to do this automatically using automapper .but i don't know what is automapper

Comment: @SSC ok, give me a few minutes to see how you can avoid it. However, I don't see why you don't want to do it this way.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios.hi ,i think this is a good idea .i decide to use this.